# How to make rounded div length based on the text within it?

Tags: css

I'm trying to add text inside rounded div element:

```
<div class='roundText'>
        Hi there!
</div>
```

and css

```
.roundText {
    width: 60px;
    height:60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 10px solid #94BBEB;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

is there any way doing this ?
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NGpJ5/)

Comment: what about if i put a few words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGpJ5/1/)

Take away the `width` and replace it with:

```
display:inline-block;
```

It looks like it doesn't fit because it's at the top, but if you put in the style:

In the case you want, you need some javascript:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGpJ5/6/)

You need to delete the `height` css attribute, then get the width of the box and set the height of it the same to make it a circle.

```
var round = document.getElementsByClassName("roundText")[0];
var width = round.offsetWidth;
round.style.height = width+"px";
```

Then if you want the text to be central (in both height and width), you can add this style:

```
text-align:center;
```

However, because javascript is making the height dynamically, you need to add more JS to set the line height.

Which is:

```
round.style.lineHeight = width+"px";
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGpJ5/7/)

Comment: but when I remove width it looks like oval shape and i do not want this it should remain rounded..

Comment: Updated answer @Tukhsanov with second jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Add a line-height with height of your div and set text-align to center

```
.roundText {
    width: 60px;
    height:60px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 10px solid #94BBEB;
    background: #ddd;
    line-height : 60px;
    text-align : center;
}
```

Comment: why you set a fixed width and height in your example ? You want a rounded div which take the size of its content ?

Answer (score 0):

By giving `display:inline-block;` & some `padding` also you can get this result. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NGpJ5/12/)

`line-height` is added & `border-radius` are also tweaked.